# why CSS is not in my second div in cordova

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have this 2 div in my body, the first one shows tables, the second one has a form with input select and buttom, and it must shows itself when i click a table from the first one, this tables call a function that hide the first div with `id="pagina1"` and the show the div with `id="pagina2"`, using the command `$("#pagina1").hide()` and `$("#pagina2").show()`, the problem is that for some reason css is not working the both div, it only works in the first div that it is declared

```HTML
<div data-role="page" id="pagina1">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>LISTADO DE REMITOS PENDIENTES </h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    <div id="idResultado"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="pagina2">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Registro de Remito </h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <div class="titlepage">Ingrese los datos </div>
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
      <input type="text" id="txtCodRemito" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Codigo Remito" required />
      <input type="datetime-local" id="txtfecha" name="birthdaytime">
      <select id="cbProveedor">
        <option value="-1">Seleccione un Proveedor</option>
      </select>
      <select id="cbCombustible">
        <option value="A">Seleccione un Combustible</option>
        <option value="B">Debe Seleccionar un proveedor para cargar los combustibles</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" id="txtLitros" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Litros Cargados" required />
      <input type="text" id="txtMonto" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Monto Total" required />
      <button id="btnCamara">Foto de Remito</button>
      <div style="border: 1px solid; width: 200px; min-height:100px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <img src="" id="myImage" />
      </div>
      <button id="btnRegistrar">Registrar</button>
    </div>
    <div id="idResultado"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my index.css ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:

```
@import url('index.css');
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

 body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    background-color:#E4E4E4;
    background-image:linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #A7A7A7 0%, #E4E4E4 51%);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        left bottom,
        color-stop(0, #A7A7A7),
        color-stop(0.51, #E4E4E4)
    );
    background-attachment:fixed;
    font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'HelveticaNeue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    /*text-transform:uppercase;*/
    width:100%;
    
    /*background-color:#32383d;
    font-family: 'RobotoRegular', 'Droid Sans', 'Segoe UI', Segoe, 'San Francisco', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;*/
}

.app {
    background: url(../images/cordova.png) no-repeat center top; 
    position: absolute;             
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 50px;                  
    width: 225px;                   
    text-align: center;
    padding: 180px 0px 0px 0px;     
    margin: -115px 0px 0px -112px;
}

@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) and (min-width:400px) {
    .app {
        background-position:left center;
        padding:75px 0px 75px 170px;
        margin:-90px 0px 0px -198px;
    }
}

h1 {
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0px;
    overflow:visible;
    padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
}

.event {
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0px 30px;
    padding:2px 0px;
}

.event.listening {
    background-color:#333333;
    display:block;
}

.event.received {
    background-color:#4B946A;
    display:none;
}

@keyframes fade {
    from { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.4; }
    to { opacity: 1.0; }
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.4; }
    to { opacity: 1.0; }
}
 
.blink {
    animation:fade 3000ms infinite;
    -webkit-animation:fade 3000ms infinite;
}

img {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
}

table {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    /*box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px black;*/
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -6px black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: We might need the CSS to try to understand why your CSS is partially working

Comment: You have probably mismanaged CSS priorities, which blocks your hide() / show()

Comment: into really i have just to check my console, when the page loads it only gives the class to the first div but not to the second one

Comment: acabo de  subir el codigo del css